# How to track when Firebase Functions Task Queues have exhausted all retries?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am using Firebase Functions Task Queues to call numerous API endpoints.

Each function is set to retry 5 times if it encounters an error.

Now I want to track if the function completes successfully or fails completely (i.e. all retries are exhausted and the function still throws an error).

I want to track this so that if it fails completely I can update a Firestore document or send an alert of some kind.

For example, here is a Task Queue function, how do I add the above functionality?

```TypeScript
export const someTask = functions.tasks
  .taskQueue({
    retryConfig: {
      maxAttempts: 5,
      minBackoffSeconds: 60,
    },
    rateLimits: {
      maxConcurrentDispatches: 1,
    },
  })
  .onDispatch(
    async () => {
      try {
        // Call the API
        await apiCall();
        return;
      } catch (error) {
        // Throw error so that the Task Queue will retry
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
          'unknown',
          'someTask error'
        );
      }
    }
  );
```

Comment: I haven't tinkered with Cloud Tasks, but I'm pretty sure you'll need to provide your own UUID in the task's data as `TaskContext` doesn't extend from `EventContext` which contains an `eventId` property. You can try `async (_, { eventId }) => { console.log(eventId) }` and see if you get anything.

Comment: You can also make use of return promise and then use that to trigger update document function

Comment: @samthecodingman I'm using TypeScript and I get `Property 'eventId' does not exist on type 'TaskContext'.ts(2339)` warning when I try your code. How would it look if I added my own UUID and why would doing that help? @RoopaM can you please show me what you mean with some code? Because I don't understand your solution right now.

Comment: You can have a look at this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=652XeeKNHSk&t=34s)

Comment: @RoopaM that video only explains that background functions must return a promise. It does not tell us how to track when Task Queues have exhausted all retries. If you know how to do that can you please show me in an answer with code provided?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This cannot be done natively with because the `context` argument provided by `onDispatch` only holds authentication details  :(

So we have to track it outside the function.

This example updates a Firestore document for each retry, success, or complete failure. There is a Firstore collection named `functionStatus` and the ID of each document is equal to the name of the function you want to track. In this example the document ID would be `someTask`. This naming convention makes it easier to update the status.

```TypeScript
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

const increment = admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment;

export const someTask = functions.tasks
  .taskQueue({
    retryConfig: {
      maxAttempts: 5,
      minBackoffSeconds: 60,
    },
    rateLimits: {
      maxConcurrentDispatches: 1,
    },
  })
  .onDispatch(async () => {
    try {
      // Call the API
      await apiCall();
    } catch (error) {
      // Get the functionStatus someTask doc
      const someTaskDoc = await admin
        .firestore()
        .collection('functionStatus')
        .doc('someTask')
        .get();

      if (someTaskDoc.data()?.retries < 5) {
        // Update the retry count because we have retries left
        await admin
          .firestore()
          .collection('functionStatus')
          .doc('someTask')
          .update({ retries: increment(1) });
      } else {
        // Update the status to failed because retries are spent
        await admin
          .firestore()
          .collection('functionStatus')
          .doc('someTask')
          .update({ status: 'failed' });
      }

      // Throw the error to start the retry (or if retries are spent kill the function completely)
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', 'someTask error');
    }

    // Everything worked. Mark function as successful
    await admin
      .firestore()
      .collection('functionStatus')
      .doc('someTask')
      .update({ status: 'success' });
  });
```